# how to assign value to "createOnElement" at runtime in smooks config?

Tags: java, groovy, smooks

```
       <jb:bean beanId="xyz" 
       class="package.xzy" 
        createOnElement="harcoded" />
```

I need to remove the harcoded string at runtime so is there any way to do this?

Comment: Can you provide context to it?

Answer (score 0):

I did this by adding the bean at runtime where bean id is modified at runtime also createOnElement is replaced by some condition.

```
      ExecutionContext execContext =smooks.createExecutionContext();
      execContext.getBeanContext().addBean(valAtRuntime,xyz);
```